# Will a message scheduled with scheduleOnce be sent if the actor specified has been stopped?

Tags: scala, akka

I schedule a message using `scheduleOnce`:

```
val cancellableMessage = system.schedule.scheduleOnce(500 milliseconds, self, "hi")
```

Then I run a method which, at its end, does this:

```
cancellableMessage.cancel()
context.stop(self)
```

I've seen questions about scheduling messages which are recurring, e.g. [Akka Scala actor scheduled message does not appear to fire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22940199/akka-scala-actor-scheduled-message-does-not-appear-to-fire), in which a dead letter is logged, because the actor was stopped. But these were recurring messages. Will I still see a dead letter if I used `scheduleOnce` instead in the manner above? Is Akka able to recognize that since I wanted to tell a message to `self` and later I stopped `self`, it will not deliver the message?

What I am afraid of is that the 500 milliseconds will occur before I can correctly cancel its sending (as there is a particular point at which I know that, no matter what, I can cancel it), but after I enter the method which cancels it, resulting in dead letters. Not a catastrophe, but certainly unpleasant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe since scheduler is done at ActorSystem level, it does not check the recipient of the message. You can imagine that your scheduler wraps `self ! "hi"` inside a Runnable and just submit the runner to the executor and it blindly executes that.

So, even if your recipient is dead, the message will be sent to the corresponding ActorRef and will end up in DeadLetter.

Comment: Thanks. That confirms what I was seeing but I wasn't sure which of my tests was causing the dead letter.